# UbuntuOne to external drive automatically

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, sync

So my desktop only has a 40gb HDD so I have a 320gb usb external drive always attached. I want to have Ubuntu One Sync to my external instead of the internal. I have 67gb of data on my UbuntuOne, more than the copacity of my internal. But I can't find a way to change where UbuntuOne downloads my files to on my machine. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One will only synchronize data in folders which are under your home directory.

You can synchronize other folders than `~/Ubuntu One/` to the service, which are under your home directory, and choose not to synchronize certain ones onto devices which do not have the capacity to store all the data in them, however.

Comment: So can I change the home directory to the external drive?

Comment: You could move your home directory to an external drive via system configuration changes, yes. That is not specific to Ubuntu One, and not a setting in Ubuntu One itself, though.